# Why isnt printing?

Tags: c++, arrays, undefined-behavior

My screen isn't printing please help me with this.I'm a beginner and i'm trying to make snake game.

```
void myScreen()
{
    char screen[30][50];
    int x = 30, y = 50;
    for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++)
    {
        if (i == 1 || i == x)
            for (int j = 1; j <= y; j++)
                screen[i][j] = '#';
        else
            for (int j = 1; j <= y; j++)
                if (j == 1 || j == y)
                    screen[i][j] = '#';
                else
                    screen[i][j] = ' ';
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= y; j++)
            cout << screen[i][j];
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

the screen isn't printing

Comment: what did you see in the debugger?

Comment: [Inferior 1 (process 8280) exited with code 030000000472]
Debugger finished with status 0

Comment: also please you should be using indexes that range from 0 to 29 not 1 to 30

Comment: You seem to be fighting tooth and nail against the fact that C is a zero-based indexing architecture for array sequences. [Don't do that.](https://godbolt.org/z/4Yovbx36h) Dance with the one you brung.

Comment: You do have a main function, right?

Comment: i means step through the code with a debugger, line by line, watch whats happening

Comment: @SuperStormer more importantly, is there a call to MyScreen in that main?

Comment: https://ideone.com/vHozp9 ignoring the out of bounds read (due to a 1-indexed print loop), the code prints the output. Of course, OOB is undefined behavior, so anything can happen.

Answer (score 2):

C++ arrays are zero-based. That means that the "first" element has actually the index 0. So your code like that:

```
for(int i=1;i<=x;i++)
```

shall be reworked like that:

```
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
```

Now back to your question: why it isn't printing? The fact is that you are accessing the memory outside of the array, and that is an Undefined Behavior in C++. That may be observed as the program that never gets to the code that prints the array.

Comment: Thank you! It works.

Comment: Then better accept the answer, as many users continue giving you advices about the main function.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it becose you don't call the funtion in main()

here how to do it:

```
int main(){
  myScreen();
}
```

the int main() is when the program is starting.after you can call other functions

They have other reason like you don't import any libraries

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
```

add this in the start of your code

Comment: i already made this

Comment: do you include <iostream> and add using namespace std;

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `main` function in your code. In C++ (and C), the `main` function gets called when you start the program. All other functions that you want to be executed you have to call from this function. Additionally, you start counting your array indexes from 1 - but the first element of an array has 0 as index in most programming languages (including C, C++, Python, JavaScript, bash, …, …). This code should work:

```cpp
#inclue <iostream>

using namespace std;

void myScreen()
{
    int x = 30, y = 50;
    char screen[x][y];
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0 || i == x - 1)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
            {
                screen[i][j] = '#';
            }
        } else
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
            {
                if (j == 1 || j == y)
                {
                    screen[i][j] = '#';
                } else
                {
                    screen[i][j] = ' ';
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
        {
            cout << screen[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    myScreen();
}
```